# Pyscripter Download

Tags: python, python-3.x, download, pyscripter

I am trying to download PyScripter on Windows 10. First time round I went into the official Python site downloaded Python 3.5.1 and got PyScripter with it and I'm thinking that all is fine with the world. But then when I attempted to open pyscripter I get:

> Error: Python could not be properly initialized. We must quit.

I uninstalled and then re-installed python the way I had before but now PyScripter doesn't download with it!
So now I have 2 problems:

1. How to download PyScripter (I feel embarrassed I can't do this)
2. How to fix the Error

Thanks for the help!

Comment: PyScripter doesn't officially support Python 3.5, but there's a workaround [here](https://github.com/pyscripter/pyscripter/issues/805).

Comment: So @OrangeFlash81, what are you suggesting? How do I get PyScripter?

Answer (score 0):

Best solution for Windows 10,

1 Download Python from python.org 32-bit or 64-bit,
Default installation Location C:\Python.
2 Download PySCript 32-bit or 64-bit,
3 Install PyScript into your computer, choose Installation Location C:\Python27\PyScripter

Finished